# Joining two tables in SQL to get the SUM between two dates

Tags: sql

I'm new to SQL and this website so apologies if anything is unclear.

Basically, I got two separate tables:

Table A:

```
CustomerID | PromoStart | PromoEnd
1          | 2020-05-01 | 2020-05-30
2          | 2020-06-01 | 2020-07-30
3          | 2020-07-01 | 2020-10-15
```

Table B:

```
CustomerID | Date       | Payment |
1          | 2020-02-15 | 5000    |
1          | 2020-05-04 | 200     |
1          | 2020-05-28 | 100     |
1          | 2020-06-05 | 1000    |
2          | 2020-06-10 | 20      |
2          | 2020-07-25 | 500     |
2          | 2020-08-02 | 1000    |
3          | 2020-09-05 | 580     |
3          | 2020-12-01 | 20      |
```

What I want is to get the sum of all payments that fall between `PromoStart` and `PromoEnd` for each customer.

so the desired result would be :

```
CustomerID  | TotalPayments
1           | 300
2           | 520
3           | 580
```

I guess this would involve an inner (left?) join and a where clause however I just can't figure it out.

Comment: Please always disclose your RDBMS and version.

Comment: SELECT table_b.CustomerId, SUM(Payment) FROM table_b  JOIN table_a ON table_b.date BETWEEN table_a.promo_start AND table_a.promo_end.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a correlated subquery or `join` with aggregation.  The correlated subquery looks like:

```
select a.*,
       (select sum(b.payment)
        from b
        where b.customerid = a.customerid and
              b.date >= a.promostart and
              b.date <= a.promoend
       ) as totalpayments
from a;
```

You don't mention your database, but this can take advantage of an index on `b(customerid, date, payment)`.  By avoiding the outer aggregation, this would often have better performance than an alternative using `group by`.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I was pretty much using the exact same query but I think I just realised why it's not working - column PromoEnd has missing values. How would I go about adjusting the query so that it only uses the b.date <= a.promoend clause when a.promoend is not null?

Answer (score 1):

A `LATERAL` join would do it:

```sql
SELECT a.customer_id, b.total_payments
FROM   table_a a
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT sum(payment) AS total_payments
   FROM   table_b
   WHERE  customer_id = a.customer_id
   AND    date BETWEEN a.promo_start AND a.promo_end
   ) b ON true;
```

This assumes inclusive lower and upper bounds, and that you want to include all rows from `table_a`, even without any payments in `table_b`.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I didn't overlook something important but it seems to me simple join on range matching condition should be sufficient:

```sql
with a (CustomerID , PromoStart , PromoEnd) as (values
(1          , date '2020-05-01' , date '2020-05-30'),
(2          , date '2020-06-01' , date '2020-07-30'),
(3          , date '2020-07-01' , date '2020-10-15')
), b (CustomerID , d       , Payment ) as (values
(1          , date '2020-02-15' , 5000    ),
(1          , date '2020-05-04' , 200     ),
(1          , date '2020-05-28' , 100     ),
(1          , date '2020-06-05' , 1000    ),
(2          , date '2020-06-10' , 20      ),
(2          , date '2020-07-25' , 500     ),
(2          , date '2020-08-02' , 1000    ),
(3          , date '2020-09-05' , 580     ),
(3          , date '2020-12-01' , 20      )
)
select a.CustomerID, sum(b.Payment)
from a
join b on a.CustomerID = b.CustomerID and b.d between a.PromoStart and PromoEnd
group by a.CustomerID
```

[Db fiddle here.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=8464e3c366e1f568b2f976f6f734180b)